# passing string arguments to filter database rows in python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

i have a written the below function to filter a column in a sql query, the function takes a string argument which will be inputted in the 'where clause'

```
def summaryTable(machineid):
 df=pd.read_sql(""" SELECT fld_ATM  FROM [003_tbl_ATM_Tables] 
    WHERE (LINK <> 1) AND (fld_ATM =('machineid')) ;
     """,connection)
connection.close()
return df
```

the function returns an empty Dataframe. i know the query itself is correct 'cause i get the expected data when i 'hardcode' the machine id

Comment: 'machineid' seems to be part of the string as a word, not a variable. You should use a formatter (see https://pyformat.info/) to pass the `machineid` as a string-variable into your query

Comment: @offeltoffel No, they should **not** use string formatting for passing variables to SQL queries. It's a habit that will bite in the long run (read about SQL injection).

Comment: Could you please include the definition of `connection`, or in other words what DB-API driver you are using, if not using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Hi  Ilja. i am using - connection=pyodbc.connect() and passing the normal parameters ie server details etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `params` to pass a tuple of parameters including `machineid` to `read_sql`. pyodbc replaces the `?` character in your query with parameters from the tuple, in order. Their values will be safely substituted at runtime. This avoids dangerous string formatting issues which may result in SQL injection.

```
df = pd.read_sql(""" SELECT fld_ATM  FROM [003_tbl_ATM_Tables] 
                     WHERE (LINK <> 1) AND (fld_ATM = ?) ;
                 """, connection, params=(machineid,))
```

Comment: this doesn't work , i get the following error ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: `:name` style placeholders aren't widely supported by DB-API drivers, and pyodbc is no exception. It's more of an SQLAlchemy thing.

Comment: Fixed to avoid use of named parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `machineid` to query using ***[params](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html)***.

```
# ? is the placeholder style used by pyodbc. Some use %s, for example.
query = """ SELECT fld_ATM  FROM [003_tbl_ATM_Tables] 
        WHERE (LINK <> 1) AND (fld_ATM = ?) ;
         """
data_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine, params=(machineid, ))
```